# Error C2061: syntax error: identifier BLOBHEADER though wincrypt.h is included

Tags: c

I have a struct in C, but I'm encountering a syntax error stating:

```
C:\sv62w8\pc\sales\src\main\custom.c(2179) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'BLOBHEADER'
```

Here's my code:

```
sample.c

#include <windows.h>
#include <wincrypt.h>

//...more codes

    struct ENCRYPT_KEY_STRUCT_TYPE {
       BLOBHEADER sample_variable;
    } EncryptKeyStruct;

//...more codes
```

By the way, I'm using Microsoft Visual C++.

Thanks!

Comment: @purplepsycho It's a type-alias (`typedef`). See e.g. [this MSDN reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387453(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: To the OP: What is your target platform (i.e. which version of Windows is your target)? Which version of VC++ are you using? Is that single error line all the compiler is saying?

Comment: what are the lines immediately before the struct ENCRYPT_KEY_STRUCT_TYPE?  This is a syntax error, not an unknown identifier.  Probably something wrong prior.

Comment: The struct should be typedef struct for a .c program, unless you're overriding to compile as C++.